# Bound on non-homogeneous system of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a system of linear equations $y'=Ay+g(t)$, my textbook gives a bound $$|\phi (t)| \leq K|y|\exp[p(t-t_0)]+K\int^{t}_{t_0} \exp[p(t-s)]\,|g(s)|\,ds.$$

I am trying to show that, under certain additional assumptions, we can improve this bound to some constant for all $t$. I am confused on how this bound can include $|y|$.

To be more specific, I have improved the bound to where it only depends on $|y|$, and nothing else. How can I further improve this bound while it relies on $|y|$, something I have never encountered?

Comment: What is $\phi (t)$?

Comment: $\phi (t)$ is a solution to the differential equation $y'=Ay$

Comment: Please state this clearly in your post

Comment: What is $K$? By Grönwall you should get with $p=\|A\|$ that $$\|y(t)\|\le \|y(t_0)\|e^{p|t-t_0|}+\int_{t_0}^te^{p|t-s|}\|g(s)\|\,ds.$$ The simple equation $y'=y+1$ should convince you that no bound independent of $t$ can exist.